# sql query problem

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DELL-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=eclass;Persist Security Info=True;integrated security = true");
    myConnection.Open();
    string key = txtsearchkey.Text.ToString();

    SqlCommand q1 = new SqlCommand("select cat_id from category where cat_name='" + (ddsearchcat.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"), myConnection);
    string cat = q1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    SqlCommand q2 = new SqlCommand("select subcat_id from subcategory where subcat_name= '" + (ddsearchsubcat.SelectedItem.ToString() + "'"), myConnection);
    string subcat = q2.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    SqlCommand q3 = new SqlCommand("select adid from adType where adtype= '" + (ddsearchtype.SelectedItem.ToString()) + "'", myConnection);
    string adtype = q3.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    String date = ddsearchdays.SelectedItem.ToString();

    if (chkAdimg.Checked)
    {
        if (chkAdVideo.Checked)
        {
            SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("select title,ad_description from postad where ad_description like " + txtsearchkey + " and category_id=" + cat + " and subcategory_id=" + subcat + " and ad_id=" + adtype + " and video is not null and img_id is not null and adType INNER JOIN adType AS adType_1 ON adType.adid = adType_1.adid CROSS JOIN  category CROSS JOIN  subcategory CROSS JOIN userdetails", myConnection);           

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(query);
            ad.Fill(ds);
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                    Response.Write(dr[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query is giving me a problem saying

> An expression of non-boolean type
>   specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'INNER...

What change should I make in my query

Comment: Looks like your `SqlCommand query` line is probably the culprit. My guess is one of your queries above it that you use values from to build your `SqlCommand query` is returning a value that is invalid. You should step through it to ensure you're getting the correct values, and probably should validate those variables before using them to build another query

Comment: **First of all:** do **NOT** string together your SQL queries! Do you know [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/) ?? Don't do that - not EVER. Use **parametrized queries** instead!

Answer (score 1):

```
select title,ad_description from postad where ad_description like " + txtsearchkey + " and category_id=" + cat + " and subcategory_id=" + subcat + " and ad_id=" + adtype + " and video is not null and img_id is not null and adType INNER JOIN adType AS adType_1 ON adType.adid = adType_1.adid CROSS JOIN  category CROSS JOIN  subcategory CROSS JOIN userdetails", myConnection);
```

where are you using inner join after where condition??

i think this may be right

```
select title,ad_description 
from postad 
INNER JOIN adType AS adType_1 ON adType.adid = adType_1.adid 
CROSS JOIN category 
CROSS JOIN subcategory 
CROSS JOIN userdetails 
where ad_description like " + txtsearchkey + " 
  and category_id=" + cat + " 
  and subcategory_id=" + subcat + " 
  and ad_id=" + adtype + " 
  and video is not null 
  and img_id is not null
```

Comment: adType INNER JOIN adType AS adType.adid=atType_1.adid

Comment: trying to use inner join in where clause?  try to use it before where clause

Comment: And again: this should utilize **parametrized queries** - and why all those `CROSS JOIN`s ?? That's going to blow up the amount of response rows like crazy!

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's here where you've got

```
...and adType INNER JOIN adType...
```

Your joins should be done before the WHERE clause, not to mention you really should be using parameters for the values instead of plain text to avoid things like sql injection, and you will probably need %'s in the values you want to do a LIKE on, but I digress...

Answer (score 0):

The varchar columns should have quotes enclosing the value. For example

```
where ad_description like " + txtsearchkey + " and
```

should be

```
where ad_description like '" + txtsearchkey + "' and
```

In addition

```
img_id is not null and adType INNER JOIN
```

should have

```
img_id is not null INNER JOIN
```

i.e. the adType seems to be misplaced.

This is not a good way of making dynamic SQL. Not only it exposes to SQL injection but also is almost impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You have your joins after your `WHERE` clause and it needs to be before the `WHERE` clause and after the `FROM`

```
select 
    title,
    ad_description 
from postad 
INNER JOIN adType AS adType_1 ON adType.adid = adType_1.adid 
CROSS JOIN  category 
CROSS JOIN  subcategory 
CROSS JOIN userdetails
where ad_description like " + txtsearchkey + " 
and category_id=" + cat + " 
and subcategory_id=" + subcat + " 
and ad_id=" + adtype + " 
and video is not null 
and img_id is not null 
and adType "
```